# How to simulate a touch event with frida in Iphone (already jailbreak)

Tags: ios-simulator, simulate, frida

I have already jailbreak the Iphone and then Installed Frida framework.
But how to send a touch event with frida? And what's the cmd about it?
3ks all

Comment: As far as I know there is no simple solution for simulating touches on iOS apps. Usually it is simpler to call the "onClick" handler directly without simulating the touch. However each UI framework implements their handler a little bit different so you have to need a lot of Frida skills to execute a button click.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of native tapping by coordinates like Android ( `adb shell input tap x y` )

3 different options;

1. Load an external module; https://github.com/zjjno/PTFakeTouchDemo

```js
Module.load("/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/PTFakeTouch.dylib")
var tap = new NativeFunction(Module.findExportByName(null, "touchxy"), "void", ["int", "int"]);
tap(x, y);
```

2. Emulate home button click

```js
ObjC.schedule(ObjC.mainQueue, function() {
  ObjC.classes.SBUIController.sharedInstance().handleHomeButtonSinglePressUp();
});
```

3. Click random element, get the list of visual elements, filter by text or type and find a button which you can invoke `tap()` on

```js
ObjC.classes.UIWindow.keyWindow().recursiveDescription().toString() // returns the view hierarchy
```

Comment: this method is to create js file? and load for run.But how to control through the pc(frida)?

Comment: what are you asking ?

Comment: well,what's the frida Api for Simulate touch event